# Datetime picker and color picker doesn't work for dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create fields dynamically after button click. The fields contain color picker and time picker - but when the controls open you cannot select from them. Although both color picker and time picker are working fine in the non-dynamic part of the page.

I think the jQuery/javascript cannot *see* the dynamic part.

I could use some help.

[This is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifhcb.png)

This is the function that creates the new row:

```
function addNewActinity(tt, day) {
    debugger
    var div = $("<tr />");
    var rows = $('#TextBoxContainer tr').length;

    $('#activitiesRow').clone().attr('id', 'activitiesRow' + rows).show()
        .appendTo('#TextBoxContainer')
        .find('input').attr('class', 'myDatepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'hh:mm',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            allowInputToggle: true})
}
```

Comment: When you append the new elements you need to instantiate the datepicker on them.

Comment: i appended it already but also still not work

Comment: We need to see your code in order to help you, otherwise we're just guessing as to what the problem is

Comment: function addNewActinity(tt, day) {
        debugger
        var div = $("<tr />");
        var rows = $('#TextBoxContainer tr').length;
        // div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(rows));
        $('#activitiesRow').clone().attr('id', 'activitiesRow' + rows).show()
            .appendTo('#TextBoxContainer')
            .find('input').attr('class', 'myDatepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'hh:mm',
                ignoreReadonly: true,
                allowInputToggle: true})
}

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code, as it's unreadable in the comments

Comment: is this ok now?

Comment: @AmanyAbdelkader - For future reference: you added the code sample exactly right, just with one small mistake: you must add a blank line between your last line of text and the indented code sample. Otherwise, excellent. Good job, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gibberish

Answer (score 1):

You will have to re-attach the Date Picker and Color Picker after you dynamically create them.

So after you create the new element dynamically, you give it ID. use this ID to attach the Date/Color Picker after creation (`$('#datepickerID').datepicker();`) you can also use JQuery selectors for class name. (`$('.datepicker').datepicker();`)

please reference these:

[Jquery datepicker on dynamically created inputs changing the date of the first input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697154/jquery-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-inputs-changing-the-date-of-the-first-i)

[Use JQuery Datepicker on dynamically created fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694306/use-jquery-datepicker-on-dynamically-created-fields)

Comment: i used this but also not work    $(document).on("click", ".myDatepicker", function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            format: 'hh:mm'
        });
    });

Comment: @AmanyAbdelkader this line should not be chained, it shoud be directly from JQuery ".find('input').attr('class', 'myDatepicker').datepicker(" to be "$.find('input').attr('class', 'myDatepicker').datepicker("

Comment: it worked with me when using this 
  $(document).on("click", ".myDatepicker", function () {
        $(".myDatepickerTxt").timepicker();
    });
and add script for jquery-ui